# How to play such http file in Exo player?

Tags: android, stream, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using exoplayer to play online streams. When I pass links form some public ip server it works fine

```
MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse("https://storage.googleapis.com/exoplayer-test-media-0/play.mp3"));
```

The above url works fine.

But when I use my own url like

```
 MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse("http://admin:admin@192.168.0.4:8732/cam4/ERecordings/4_UNIVIEW_192.168.1.13/01-07-2020/14-39-23.mp4"));
```

It shows error.
I pasted the exact same url in vlc and mx android player and they works fine and every device is working on same wifi.

Error:

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
    com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 401
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:211)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:147)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:844)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:320)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: > It shows error. 

What error does it show?

Comment: please check I have added error message, It is showing internal source error. It basically can not access file from my server but every other player can.

Comment: HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 401   → Response code 401 is "Unauthorized" . Are you even connected to local server/vpn ? can you open "http://admin:admin@192.168.0.4:8732/cam4/ERecordings" from phone?

Comment: Yes I can open it with some browser or other media players. Even VLC integration libvlc can play this.